# force of hail falling straight

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, weather

There is a hail storm and it's falling straight down (0 wind factor) will the hail meet a moving car with greater force than a car standing still?

Comment: Your question could use an edit. As stated it says "There is a hail storm and it's falling straight down (0 wind factor) will the hail meet a moving car with greater force than a car standing still (will meet a moving car)?". The answer to that is probably no.

Comment: Ar you asking for the net force?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will. The effective velocity of the hail is the vector sum of the velocity of the falling hail and the moving car - this means the windshield will be hit by hail going faster and thus having more momentum. To reverse this momentum will require a greater $F\Delta t$ .

Note - I did say "hit the windshield" - or more generally any forward facing component. It won't change the force on the roof and there may be areas like the rear window that will experience less impact (maybe none at all).

If your car is a rectangular box, then in the stationary case there is no hail hitting the front or rear; just the top. When the car (box) is moving, the same number of hail stones will be hitting the roof per unit time, and their vertical velocity will be the same. Assuming that the hail stone bounce off with a perfectly elastic collision (no sliding friction), then the force on the roof is unchanged.

The same is not true for the front of the car / box. When it was stationary, nothing hit the front; now that it is moving, the car "intercepts" hail that is falling straight down.

You can calculate the force due to this if you know the density of the hail (mass of hail / unit volume). The volume of air-with-hail that is swept by the car in unit time is

$$vol = v_{car}A_{car}$$

In words: the volume equals the velocity times the area of the car (the front facing surface of the "box").  The total amount of hail that is hit is thus

$$m_{hail}=vol \cdot \rho_{hail}$$

and since the velocity of the hail changes by $2v_{car}$ (elastic collision assumed), the change of momentum in the car's frame of reference is $2 m_{hail} v_{car}$. Since this is in unit time, the (new) force on the car due to hitting the hail is

$$F=2 \rho_{hail} v_{car}^2 A_{car}$$

For any $v_{car}>0$ this says there is an additional force from the hail on the car because it is moving.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Consider the Newtonian reference frame.

Case 1:  Stationary car.  The hail falls straight down on the roof of the car, striking it at velocity:  $V = (0,V_y)$ where $V$ = velocity vector of ($V_x, V_y$) and y is the vertical direction.  Here the hail has momentum p = (mass) x (velocity).

Case 2:  Moving car.  The car is moving at velocity $V_x$.  Consider the moving reference frame (you feel stationary in the car and the hail is now moving at $V = (-V_x, V_y)$.  The total velocity of the hail is now:  magnitude($V$) = $\sqrt{V_x^2 + V_y^2} > V_y$.  Therefore the momentum of the hail is larger when the car is moving.  Therefore the force on the car is greater when the car is moving.